# How do I pause one of the NSTimer thats running then resume it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have one timer firing to go to a void statement. Which has another timer in it. I want to pause the one thats firing or going off then resume it.

```
movement3 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(jone) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


- (void)jone{

[jumperguy setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jumperguy_a_a3.png"]];

movement4 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(jtwo) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott I tried implementing this before it didn't work out for me. Could be doing something wrong. I got a few errors.

Comment: Please post your exact issue and real code as your comments indicate you are doing something different from the question you have posted.

Comment: It is impossible to pause or resume a timer, see the question yours was marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

You can only `invalidate` an [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) object to stop it. You can have two methods such as:

```
-(void) pauseTimer:(NSTimer *) timer {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
-(void) resumeTimer:(NSTimer *) timer {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(jone) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: I want to check which timer is running so I can invalidate it then start the timer up again. Like above I said I have multiple timers firing. So when one timer is done then it goes to another timer which is in a void statement and so on.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. Could you please give us an example scenario including your other timers? The 1 line of code you have in your question is not even a repeating timer! It'll run once, and that's it. What do you mean by "the current timer thats running" ?!

Comment: For an example I have multiple timers firing to set a image thats in each timer and I want to stop the timer so it stops on the current image it is on. Then resume the timer so the timer can move on doing its thing.

Comment: @TylerSchoenau you need to either update your question with more descriptive explanations and the complete code you're using, or find a new way to achieve what you're trying to do. I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. "I have multiple timers firing to set a image thats in each timer" makes no sense to me. How can you have an "image thats in each timer" ? Are you talking about a different NSTimer object or something else?

Comment: Yeah the different images are in different NSTimers.

Comment: Tyler, you can't have images "in" NSTimers man! It just doesn't make sense. Could you please just copy paste your code so I can see what you're talking about?

Comment: movement3 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(jone) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


- (void)jone{
    
   [jumperguy setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"jumperguy_a_a3.png"]];
 
   movement4 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(jtwo) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste everything there? Maybe some screenshots of the UI would help. Thanks.